# Как найти все новые файлы (после установки пакета) в Linux

Tags: linux, bash

После установки какого либо пакета в linux хочется увидеть все файлы которые были установлены. Каким образом найти абсолютно все файлы во всей файловой системе?

Уточню вопрос.
Смысл не просто увидеть файлы пакета, а понять в каких директориях оказываются эти файлы после установки.

Comment: `sudo find / -type f` и ложись спать

Comment: @nörbörnën `все файлы которые были установлены` ...при установке пакета. Так что шутка несколько неуместна, - вопрос нормальный.

Comment: @Arhad-the-dev сделать find до установки, потом после установки и сравнить :)

Comment: А вообще можно банально открыть пакет любым менеджером архивов — не все, но большинство файлов там будут

Comment: @Arhad-the-dev, а фильтр по дате не прокатит? Или они могут со старой датой записаться?

Comment: @andreymal, перезаписанные файлы так не узнаешь.

Comment: @Qwertiy пакет, перезаписывающий чужие файлы (если это не passwd), — весьма странный пакет

Comment: Как вариант, запустить докер, поставить пакет, глянуть на файловую систему, она идет "слоями".

Comment: @Arhad-the-dev `Каким образом найти абсолютно все файлы во всей файловой системе?`

Answer (score 7):

Для **Debian-based**
Есть утилита `apt-file`

```
apt-file update
apt-file list package_name
```

она покажет какие файлы есть в пакете (бинарники, скрипты запуска, конфиги etc).

Для **установленных** пакетов можно воспользоваться:

```
dpkg -L package_name
```

Для **CentOS**

```
rpm -ql package_name
```

Важно понимать, что некоторые файлы могут быть не указаны этими утилитами, т.к. они могут генерироваться на этапе установки пакета.

Если нужно отслеживать какие файлы изменились при обновлении пакета, то можно скриптом пробежаться по списку файлов и проверить дату модификации/изменения файла: `stat путь_до_файла`.

Comment: Хочется увидеть также в каких местах они будут находиться